# My ansible playbook get stuck at particular task while using make command to install postgresql

Tags: ansible

PLAY [demo] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [postgresql-role : create postgres user] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [postgresql-role : create postgres group] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [postgresql-role : create postgresql directory] *******************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [postgresql-role : Install some postgresql dependent packages] ****************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "yum" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of using a loop to supply multiple items and specifying
`name: "{{ item }}"`, please use `name: ['readline-devel', 'zlib-devel', 'gcc', 'make']` and remove the loop. This feature will be removed in version 2.11. Deprecation
warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'readline-devel', u'zlib-devel', u'gcc', u'make'])

TASK [postgresql-role : Download postgresql] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [postgresql-role : Extract postgresql files] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [postgresql-role : create postgres database source tree] **********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [postgresql-role : start your postgresql build using make command] -----** Get stuck at this point**

Team, please guide me for this solution.

Note: Yesterday it worked absolutely fine but today when I run the playbook it not moving further and not even showing any error or standard logs

Comment: Maybe share the details of that task so somebody might be able to help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, I have updated some PostgreSQL dependencies packages and run the playbook and it worked.

Thanks for your support and initiative.

Comment: What dependencies did you update? Without this information, this doesn’t offer a solution for future readers with the same problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).